# Is it possible to decrypt RSA sign value in JAVA?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, sign

So as far as I understand, sign usually comes with data, sign value is to make sure the data value has never been revised, the principle is to decrypt sign then compare with the data see if they are exactly the same, in Java it gives you true if they are, false otherwise.

my question is now: I get response from an API and it contains data and sign value, I can manage to decrypt the data (yes the data is encrypted as well) to get plaintext but somehow when it process to verify the sign it gives me false everytime.
now I'm wondering what's the difference between the decrypted sign and data, there must be some inconsistency as it gives me false.

is there the other way round to check it?

Comment: The signature is (essentially, ignore specifics) an asymmetrically encrypted **hash** of the data. To verify, you use the public key to "decrypt" the hash and compare it to a hash of the received data. A cryptographic hash is by definition a surjective function and therefore cannot be reversed. So short answer, no - without looking at the plaintext data on both sides of the interaction there is no way to determine what the difference is.

Comment: Perhaps the signature is over the ciphertext and not the plaintext?